# How do I get the line and error type when performing a php lint check?

Tags: php, command-line

When I run $ php -l /path/to/script.php it will report whether an error occurs or not, but won't indicate the line or error type when an error does occur. Is there a better command line tool for lint checking or another way to get more error information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd, `php -l` reports errors just fine for me. test.php test script:

```
<?php
    random_function_name('blah);
                              ^--- missing closing quote
```

gives me:

```
marc@panic:~/z$ php -l test.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting ')' in test.php on line 2
Errors parsing test.php
marc@panic:~/z$
```

Check your `error_reporting` and `display_errors` settings and make sure that errors aren't being supressed.

Comment: Thanks, it must have been my php.ini settings.

Comment: To avoid a bad `error_reporting` definition being used, you can use `php -nl test.php`. 
`-n` stands for `No php.ini file will be used`